# How to define the "MODULE DOCS" for display with pydoc?

Tags: python, module, pydoc

The pydoc documentation of some Python modules (like `math` and `sys`) has a "MODULE DOCS" section that contains a useful link to some HTML documentation:

```
Help on module math:

NAME
    math

FILE
    /sw/lib/python2.6/lib-dynload/math.so

MODULE DOCS
    /sw/share/doc/python26/html/math.html
```

How can such a section be included in your own modules?

More generally, is there a place where the variables recognized by pydoc are documented?

I was not able to find this in the source because the `math` module is a shared library, on my machine (OS X), and the `sys` module is built in Python…  Any help would be much appreciated!

Answer (score 3, accepted):

After looking in the code of the `pydoc` module, I think that the "MODULE DOCS" link is only available for standard modules, not custom ones.

Here is the relevant code:

```
def getdocloc(self, object):
    """Return the location of module docs or None"""

    try:
        file = inspect.getabsfile(object)
    except TypeError:
        file = '(built-in)'

    docloc = os.environ.get("PYTHONDOCS",
                            "http://docs.python.org/library")
    basedir = os.path.join(sys.exec_prefix, "lib",
                           "python"+sys.version[0:3])
    if (isinstance(object, type(os)) and
        (object.__name__ in ('errno', 'exceptions', 'gc', 'imp',
                             'marshal', 'posix', 'signal', 'sys',
                             'thread', 'zipimport') or
         (file.startswith(basedir) and
          not file.startswith(os.path.join(basedir, 'site-packages'))))):
        if docloc.startswith("http://"):
            docloc = "%s/%s" % (docloc.rstrip("/"), object.__name__)
        else:
            docloc = os.path.join(docloc, object.__name__ + ".html")
    else:
        docloc = None
    return docloc
```

A return value of None is interpreted as an empty "MODULE DOCS" section.

Answer (score 0):

Module documentation is probably the [docstring of the module](http://www.python.org/dev/peps/pep-0257/). This is a plain text (or [restructured text](http://docutils.sourceforge.net/rst.html)) string occurring at the top of your module. Here is an example.

```
"""
Module documentation.
"""

def bar():
    print "HEllo"
```

This is for pure Python modules.

For compiled extension modules (like `math`), You pass the module docstring (as a Python string) as the 3rd argument to `Py_InitModule3` when you're initialising your module. That will make the string the module docstring. You can see this being done in the source for the math module [here](http://svn.python.org/view/python/trunk/Modules/mathmodule.c?view=markup).

Comment: The "MODULE DOCS" section is different from the docstring of the module.  "pydoc math" shows an example.

Comment: Can you paste a snippet of the content? I don't see such a section when I do a `pydoc math`.

Comment: I added what `pydoc math` yields on my machine, in the original post.